# Visual Studio: Change parameter order with hot keys

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I don't want to change the signature of a method, I would like to change the order of parameters while using a method:

```
RandomVoidMethod(parameter3, parameter1, parameter2)
```

to

```
RandomVoidMethod(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3)
```

With resharper I am normally able to press

> Ctrl+Shift+Alt+Left / Ctrl+Shift+Alt+Right

and let the parameter move to the letf/right. Is there something similar in VS Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no, this is not supported by Visual Studio out of the box. Only changing the signature (Ctrl+R, Ctrl+O) then clicking the move arrows in the dialog.

You can see the list of keyboard shortcuts here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Comment: In the change signature dialog, you can move the parameters with the keyboard, by holding down alt and using the arrow keys.